# Не могу найти ошибку IndexError

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, while

меня мучает **`IndexError`**

```
import random
import sys
import time
import os
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import keyboard

init()

line = 0
os.chdir("D:/")
files_dir = os.listdir()
while True:
    file_dir_inx = 1
    while len(files_dir):
        element = files_dir[file_dir_inx]
        file_dir_inx = file_dir_inx+1
        if line == file_dir_inx:
            print( Back.BLUE + Fore.WHITE + element)
        else:
            print( Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + element)
    print( Back.BLUE + Fore.RESET + "")
    print( Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + os.getcwd())
    if keyboard.read_key() == "up":
        line = int(line-1)
    if keyboard.read_key() == "down":
        line = int(line+1)
    print( Back.RESET + Fore.RESET )
    os.system('cls')
```

Я знаю, что она на строке 18, 
но там все пишет правильно и я не знаю, что делать (все что могу пробовал).

Comment: Вы в цикле бесконечно увеличиваете число `file_dir_inx` — вполне логично, что однажды оно увеличится настолько, что выражение `files_dir[file_dir_inx]` вылезет за правый край списка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему так происходит, вам в комментарии написал @andreymal

Попробуйте так:

```
#import random
#import sys
#import time
import os
from colorama import init
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import keyboard

init()

line = 0
os.chdir("D:/_Qt/__Qt/temp/")                               # ! установите свой путь

files_dir = os.listdir()
len_files_dir = len(files_dir)                              # +

running = True                                              # +
while running:
    file_dir_inx = 0                                        # ? 1, почкму один ?
    
#    while len(files_dir) :
    while file_dir_inx < len_files_dir :                    # +
        element = files_dir[file_dir_inx]
        file_dir_inx = file_dir_inx + 1
        if line == file_dir_inx:
            print( Back.BLUE + Fore.WHITE + element)
        else:
            print( Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + element)
            
    print( Back.BLUE + Fore.RESET + "")
    print( Back.WHITE + Fore.BLACK + os.getcwd())
    
    key = keyboard.read_key()                                # + 
    if key == "up":
        line = int(line - 1)
#-> vvvv
    elif key == "down":
        line = int(line + 1)

    elif key == "esc":                           # + чтобы было как выйти из цикла
        running = False
        
    print(f'line = {line}') #
    print( Back.RESET + Fore.RESET )
    os.system('cls')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]